# How to ask for return receipt and set importance in Mutt?

Tags: linux, email, smtp, mutt

I would like to be able to ask for a return receipt and set importance levels in emails when I am sending emails from Mutt (using Mutt Smtp sender).

I can not find a way online, maybe not doing the right kind of search.

Ideally I would like this to be automated but manual solutions are fine as well.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_receipt#Message_disposition_notifications) on Wikipedia, a `Return-Receipt-To:` header should do the trick in many cases (it is non standard, but widely supported).

Similar headers exist for priority and importance level.

In your mutt configuration file, include:

```
set hdrs=yes
my_hdr Return-Receipt-To: myself@example.com
my_hdr X-Priority: 1
my_hdr Importance: high
```

You can add or modify these headers manually for each message if you have the [edit headers](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-6.html#edit_headers) option set.

[Here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.mail.mutt.user/41518) is a way to add keyboard macros for setting priority before editing the message.

Success of receipt request depends on the mail user agent and the user on the other end. You cannot enforce it.